# How to set font style light?

Tags: css, fonts, flash-cs5, photoshop

I m making a web site from photoshop sketch.
And I have a text wit

> font-family Segoe Ui and font-style: Light.
>   In photoshop It looks like this:[image]

So how to set this in css to p element?

```
p {

}
```

Comment: `font-weight:lighter` - but only if the font supports light. This was one google-search to go

Comment: Segoe UI is a font copyrighted by Microsoft, so unless you have a licence to do so, you can't use this as a Web Font.

Comment: You can use font-weight: lighter

Comment: @adaam: the OP does not mention "webfont". Defining it in a CSS is okay; and it will only be used when the *browser* can find it anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `font-weight` which takes values like:

```
p {
    font-weight: 100; /* 100, 200, 300, ... 900, normal, bold, bolder, lighter */
}
```

See the documentation on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp).

Comment: Please do not call W3Schools "the W3C". It is in no way affiliated with the W3C, and generally not recommended as a source, although it isn't that horrible anymore. See http://www.w3fools.com.

Answer (score 13):

Updated: [Table on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#Common_weight_name_mapping)

Value   Common weight name

- 100  Thin (Hairline)
- 200  Extra Light (Ultra Light)
- 300  Light
- 400  Normal
- 500  Medium
- 600  Semi Bold (Demi Bold)
- 700  Bold
- 800  Extra Bold (Ultra Bold)
- 900  Black (Heavy)

Old:

- 100    Extra Light or Ultra Light
- 200    Light or Thin
- 300    Book or Demi
- 400    Normal or Regular
- 500    Medium
- 600    Semibold, Demibold
- 700    Bold
- 800    Black, Extra Bold or Heavy
- 900    Extra Black, Fat, Poster or Ultra Black